# Question about expressing sorry when you are alone in front of mirror talking to yourself about what you should not do in the past

Tags: sentence-construction

Imagine that you have told your friend that she had an ugly car, yesterday.
Now today you are alone standing in front of the mirror, talking loudly to yourself. You want to tell yourself that it was not a good thing to say her that her was was ugly. And you want to use **should** or **I'd better** in negative and past tense.

Are these correct?

> I shouldn't told her that, yesterday.
>
> I shouldn't tell her that, yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

You'd say *I shouldn't have X*:

> **I shouldn't have told** her that yesterday.

Your versions aren't grammatical.  You want to use *shouldn't* plus a perfect construction, which consists of *have* plus the past participle form of the verb.

---

You can't use *I'd better* for past actions like this.  The closest expression I can think of would be something like:

> **It would have been better if I hadn't told** her that yesterday.

You can say that too, though it's a bit wordier.

---

Either way, I wouldn't put a comma before *yesterday*.

Comment: And then "I'd better get my act together."